# Absolute Values and Floors

Tags: absolute-value, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Problem:

> Find all $x$ for which
>   $$\left| x - \left| x-1 \right| \right| = \lfloor x \rfloor.$$Express your answer in interval notation.

How would I do this? There are lots of absolute value signs and a floor sign that I can't handle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=1$ is a solution.
if $x>1$ it becomes
$$1=\lfloor x \rfloor $$
whose solution is $1 <x <2$.

if $x <1$, it is

$$|2x-1|=\lfloor x \rfloor $$

if $x\geq 0,5$ we get
$$2x-1=0$$
or $$x=0,5 $$

now if $x \leq 0,5$, it becomes
$$1-2x =\lfloor x \rfloor$$ and because
$$A-1 <\lfloor A \rfloor  \leq A ,$$
$$x-1 <1-2x\leq x $$ or
$$\frac {1}{3}\leq x <\frac {2}{3}$$

and $\lfloor x \rfloor =0\implies x=0,5$.

finally, we should have
$$x\in \{0.5\}\cup [1,2 [$$

Comment: This does not look correct... How do you get the interval in the case $x <\frac{1}{2}$? One can check that, for instance, $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{5}$ are not solutions.

Comment: A graph verifies this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx-%7Cx-1%7C%7C

Comment: I don't understand your final result.  It seems obviously wrong.  The right hand is identically $0$ in the interval $[\frac 13,\frac 12]$ but the left hand is only $0$ at $\frac 12$.  Can you explain your result?

Comment: The problem is that if $|2x-1|=\lfloor x \rfloor$, then $|2x-1|$ must, in particular, be an integer. No value of $x$ in $[1/3, 1/2)$ satisfies that.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\ge 1$ then $|x-|x-1||=|x-x+1|=|1|=1=\lfloor x\rfloor\iff x\in[1,2[$

If $x<1$ then $|x-|x-1||=|x+x-1|=|2x-1|=\lfloor x\rfloor$

- If $0\le x<1$ then $|2x-1|=\lfloor x\rfloor=0\iff x=\frac 12$
- If $x<0$ then $|2x-1|>0$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor<0$ so no solutions

> Finally the solutions are $\{\frac 12\}\cup[1,2[$

Answer (score 0):

Zero is not a solution.

There can be no negative solutions because if $x<0$ then

$$ \vert x - |x-1|\vert=\vert x-(1-x) \vert= \vert 2x-1\vert=1-2x>0$$0$

and for $x<0$, $1-2x>\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Thus the only solutions would have to be positive.

$x=1$ is a solution.

If $x>1$ then $\vert x - |x-1|\vert=1$ so the only solutions for $x>1$ lie on the interval $(1,2)$.

So the only remaining question is whether there are any solutions on the interval $(0,1)$

$x=\frac{1}{2}$ is clearly a solution, so you should look for solutions on the intervals $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$.

Can you take it from here?